# Suitescript check if field is searchable

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to search Account data using SuiteScript 1.0 in netsuite, but I am getting "**SS_INVALID_SRCH_COL Details: An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax:"** error. I am using Admin role for my login. following the code sample that causing error

```
function getMasterData(datain)
{
  try
    {
      var recordtype = 'account';


      var c;
      var strcolumns = nlapiCreateRecord(recordtype).getAllFields();

      var searchcolumns = [];
      for (c = 0; strcolumns.length && c < strcolumns.length; c += 1)
      { 
            searchcolumns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn(strcolumns[c]));
      }

      var data = nlapiSearchRecord(recordtype, null, null, searchcolumns);
      return data;  
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'getMasterData', ex);
    }
    }
```

I know the reason: getAllFields() returns all the fields (searchable/nonsearchable) but nlapiSearchRecord works only for searchable fields. My query is how I can filter searchable fields in the all fields returned by getAllFields() function.

Can please anybody help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know if a field can be used in a search but you can get the supported fields from the [Records Browser](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/script/record/account.html) and create an array with them.

Note that you can get a record with all fields and values using [nlapiLoadRecord](https://system.na2.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n3027360.html#bridgehead_N3030703).